# Get most frequent elements across all groups in a Panda time series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How one can plot the `count` of the `n` most frequent elements **across all groups** for a given multi group time series? Note this is different from `n` most frequent elements of **each** group, which could be accomplished with `count` and `nlargest`.

Given a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'year': [2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022], 
        'month': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        'Name': ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_1', 'name_2', 'name_1'], 
        'count': [10, 12, 8, 10, 2]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

which outputs

```
   year  month    Name  Count
0  2020      1  name_1     10
1  2020      1  name_2     12
2  2021      2  name_1      8
3  2021      2  name_2     10
4  2022      3  name_1      2
```

---

- data should be grouped by `year` **and** `month`
- I want `n = 1`, in other words the **most** frequent one

---

I would like to plot only `name_1`'s `count` since, although it does not have the largest count in any group (or even overall), it "appears" more times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to filter the most common Name and plot the counts?

```
# get top Name
top = df['Name'].value_counts().index[0]

# filter
df2 = df[df['Name'].eq(top)]

# plot
(df2.assign(date=df2[['year', 'month']].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1))
    .plot.bar(x='date', y='count')
)
```

[image]

###### several TOP values

```
# get top Name
top = df['Name'].value_counts().index[:2]

# filter and reshape
df2 = (df[df['Name'].isin(top)]
        .pivot(index=['year', 'month'],
               columns='Name',
               values='count')
      )

# plot
df2.plot.bar()
```

[image: several top values]

Comment: Excelent starting point @mozway. Notice that I need "`n` most frequent elements". Could you please improve your answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @ThiagoPetrone sure, see update